# Is this service-provider design acceptable in Laravel?

Tags: php, oop, laravel-5.5

I have next entities: `Event`, `Ticket`. I want to get some ticket information for latest event using different data sources.

So in my controller I use DI:

```
private $latestEventService;

public function __construct()
{
    $this->latestEventService= new LatestEventService();
}
```

and inside methods:

`$this->latestEventService->getTicketsAmount();`

`app/Services/LatestEventService`:

```
private $provider;

public function __construct($provider = 'db')
{
    $this->provider = new config('services.latest_event_providers')[$provider]();
}

public function getTicketsAmount()
{
    return $this->provider->getTicketsAmount();
}

public function getFreeTicketsAmount()
{
    return $this->provider->getFreeTicketsAmount();
}

public function getDiscountedTicketsAmount()
{
    return $this->provider->getDiscountedTicketsAmount();
}
```

`config/services`:

```
'latest_event_providers' => [
    'db' => '\App\Providers\LatestEvent\DBProvider',
    'api'=> '\App\Providers\LatestEvent\APIProvider'
]
```

`DBProvider`:

```
class DBProvider extends ServiceProvider implements ILatestEventProvider
{
    public function getTicketsAmount()
    {
        //fetch from db
    }

    public function getFreeTicketsAmount()
    {
        //fetch from db
    }

    public function getDiscountedTicketsAmount()
    {
        //fetch from db
    }
}
```

`app/Interfaces/ILatestEventProvider`:

```
interface ILatestEventProvider
{
    public function getTicketsAmount();

    public function getFreeTicketsAmount();

    public function getDiscountedTicketsAmount();
}
```

Can I leave this as it is? I'm worried about `DBProvider`, it's not familiar to other "default" Laravel providers (there is no "default" `boot()` and `register()` methods).

Answer (score 1):

Service provider in Laravel is a place where you bootstrap your application. DBProvider isn't service provider it's just tickets calculator for latest event(just service)

Right DI in your controller will be

```
private $latestEvent;

public function __construct(LatestEventFactory $latestEventFactory, $provider)
{
    $this->latestEvent = $latestEventFactory->createInstance($provider);
}
```

For creating LastEvent service we use Factory design pattern

```
class LastEventFactory
{
    public function createInstance($provider): ILatestEvent
    {
        return new config('services.latest_event_providers')[$provider]();
    }
}
```

Next, you should create two classes which implement ILatestEvent (DBLastEvent and ApiLastEvent)

```
interface ILatestEvent
{
    public function getTicketsAmount();

    public function getFreeTicketsAmount();

    public function getDiscountedTicketsAmount();
}
```

In this case, you don't need service provider because Laravel service container smart enough to resolve LatestEventFactory without service provider

Comment: "you should create two classes which implement ILatestEvent" - where can I put them, on your opinion?
And about `$provider = //your logic` - I guess, this is the place to define eiter DB or API service here, but in my original post I pass this as an option.

Comment: Now, it's not very important how you organize your code, it's easy to change your structure with modern IDE. You can add Services namespace
\App\Services\DBLastEvent
Or just put them with your models
Also here you can find good ideas for your project https://medium.com/@munza/large-scale-laravel-application-9d52c3d38e51

Comment: $provider = //your logic 
You right here was logic where you define which service to use. If it depends on controller parameters, then we don't need service provider. I updated my answer